# How can i detect that if user received Remote Notification but not open it on IOS app by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to detect that if user received Remote Notification when their phones was locked but they didn't open the app by Remote Notification.Then they opened the app normally.

Now i use didReceiveRemoteNotification for detect Remote notification but when they opened the app normally it seems didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever start the app normally, it will be started as no push notification arrived. The only way (I can think of) you can display something different in this case is to connect your server at the application launch and get some information that indicates a push notification was recently sent to that device.

You can get the notification payload on didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate method but it will be only called if your application is either in foreground or user taps on the push notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    }
```

Comment: So how can i check if user open the app normally without taped remote notification.

Comment: Simple if your application is launched by notification then it will definetly call didReceiveRemoteNotification method otherwise you can assume the normal launch.